# How to toggle individual divs that have the same class

Tags: jquery

I have a set of repeated wrapper divs with several child divs. Inside each wrapper div is a div for a toggleable icon +. The idea is that when that icon is clicked it will slide down a hidden div and close all other open hidden divs. However, when I click on any +, it toggles ALL hidden divs, not just the one it's inside. Also, I have NO IDEA how to close all other divs once one slides down. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

I've tried several variations of this, and none has worked:

```
$('.action').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('div').find('.text-area').slideToggle();
```

Here's my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/9v3p7sxg/

Comment: use `$(this).closest('.row').next(".row").find('.text-area').slideToggle();` [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/9v3p7sxg/1/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, T.J. Crowder. Will do so next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following line:

```
$(this).closest('div').find('.text-area').slideToggle();
```

to

```
$(this).closest('.row').next(".row").find('.text-area').slideToggle();
```

and try again.

**Explanation:** The selector is in next `div` having class `.row` So first select the parent `row` and then select its immediately next `row`

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks so much!

Comment: That's great!! Hey you are `Building an online freelance platform`, let me know if you need some working hands

Comment: Yep, slowly but surely - one day at a time. Not at the stage where I can pay a team yet, though.

Comment: Give me your Skype id or email id, if possible?

Comment: I have send you chat invitation there

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.action').click(function()
$(this).parent().closest('div').find('.text-area').slideToggle();
```